# Regular expression to extract twitter handle in python

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I want to extract twitter handle for twitter urls like these

`1.)https://www.twitter.com/sachin`
`2.)https://www.twitter.com/@sachin`
`3.)https://www.twitter.com/@sachin`
`4.)https://www.twitter.com/sachin?lang=en`

output
sachin

I am using this regex

```
import re
match = re.search(r'^(?:.*twitter\.com/@?)(\w{1,15})(?:$|/.*$|,)',twitter_url)
handle = match.group(1)
```

The url type 1,2,3 are giving result as expected but url type 4 is not giving result and giving this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: This looks like Pandas, try `row['twitter'].str.extract(r'/@?(\w+)[^/]*$')`. Well, or just `re.search(r'/@?(\w+)[^/]*$', row['twitter']).group(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern does not match the 4th example as `(\w{1,15})` will match `sachin` and the next character is `?` and the pattern tries to match a `/`

You could optionally match the `?` and the rest of the line or specify all allowed characters using a character class `[?/,]`

```
^.*?\btwitter\.com/@?(\w{1,15})(?:[?/,].*)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline as least as possible (or use `\S*?` if there can be no spaces)
- `\btwitter\.com/@?` Match twitter.com/ and optional @
- `(\w{1,15})` Capture 1-15 word characters in group 1
- `(?:[?/,].*)?` Optionally match either `?` or `/` or `,` and the rest of the line
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fg5xYk/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/cX9sky)

For example

```
import re
twitter_urls = [
    "https://www.twitter.com/sachin",
    "https://www.twitter.com/@sachin",
    "https://www.twitter.com/@sachin",
    "https://www.twitter.com/sachin?lang=en"
]

for twitter_url in twitter_urls:
    match = re.search(r'^.*?\btwitter\.com/@?(\w{1,15})(?:[?/,].*)?$',twitter_url)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Output

```
sachin
sachin
sachin
sachin
```

Comment: This regex expression works in my case. How to handle this twitter url where there is space between username```http://twitter.com/sachin mohan```

Comment: @SACHINMOHAN You might use a pattern like `^.*?\btwitter\.com/@?(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)(?:[?/,].*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/O4KhH2/1 or perhaps `^.*?\btwitter\.com/@?([^?/,\r\n]+)(?:[?/,].*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/yo5CTF/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
r'/@?(\w+)[^/]*$'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MHzrI4/1).

*Details*:

- `/` - a `/` char
- `@?` - an optional `@` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: any one or more letters, digits or `_` chars
- `[^/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

A sample usage with `re.search`:

```py
match = re.search(r'/@?(\w+)[^/]*$', twitter_url)
if match:                   # Check if there is a match
    print(match.group(1))
else:
    print("No match")       # Action upon no match
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#module-urllib.parse)?

```
urls = ['https://www.twitter.com/sachin', 'https://www.twitter.com/@sachin',
        'https://www.twitter.com/@sachin', 'https://www.twitter.com/sachin?lang=en']

from urllib.parse import urlparse # or urlsplit

for url in urls:
    print(urlparse(url).path.lstrip('/@'))
```

output

```
sachin
sachin
sachin
sachin
```